# Mantener tamaño de <tr> fijo en una tabla HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap

Estoy ingresando unos datos en una tabla HTML, pero cuando intento ingresar un texto de un tamaño mayor la fila de la tabla también aumenta de tamaño...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, la fila inferior aumentó su tamaño respecto a la fila superior que es el tamaño original...

Como puedo mantener el tamaño de un `<tr>` o fila de la tabla fijo, independientemente del tamaño del contenido que se le ingrese, también estoy usando bootstrap:

```css
table.tabla_televisor {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #82FA58;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

table.tabla_televisor tr {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  /* PARA MARCAR LA SEPARACION LAS CELDAS DE LA TABLA  */
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

table.tabla_televisor td {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  /* PARA MARCAR LA SEPARACION LAS CELDAS DE LA TABLA  */
  height: 163px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="tabla_televisor" style="font-size: 22pt; text-align:center; padding: 0px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; width:180px; height:163px"></td>
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; width:180px;  height:163px">I4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; width:180px; height:163px">2</td>
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; width:180px; height:163px">I3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: ¡Hola! ¿Alguna respuesta fue útil?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré una solución ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/odksxe9u/2/)), pero esperaba que fuera más simple.

Primero, `cellspacing`, `cellpadding` y **estilos en línea** no son HTML5: queremos evitar mezclar DOM (HTML) y estilos (CSS).

Después de decir esto, introduje las `div` en las `td` y usé los atributos `transform` (y, si es necesario, `overflow`) de las `div`.

También tenga cuidado de no confundirse con `pt` y `px`!

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)

```css
table.tabla_televisor {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #82FA58;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 22pt;
  text-align: center
}

table.tabla_televisor tr {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

table.tabla_televisor tr td {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  width: 180px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

tr.cincuenta td {
  font-size: 50pt;
  color: #000
}

tr.cientotreinta td {
  font-size: 130pt;
  color: #f00
}

table.tabla_televisor tr td div {
  height: 163px;
  max-height: 163px;
  overflow: visible;
}

tr.cincuenta td div {
  transform: translate(0, 20px);
}

tr.cientotreinta td div {
  transform: translate(0, -60px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table class="tabla_televisor">

  <tr class="cincuenta">
    <td><div> </div></td>
    <td><div>I4</div></td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="cientotreinta">
    <td><div>2</div></td>
    <td><div>I3</div></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Excelente, era justo lo que necesitaba en aquella ocasión, y no había vuelto a revisar esto hasta que vi las notificaciones viejas e ingresé por curiosidad... Muchas gracias...

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad adecuada para definir un valor maximo del ancho de un elemento es `max-width`

Modificando tu documento seria así. (modificale el valor. puse 150px a modo de ejemplo)

```
 <table class="tabla_televisor" style="font-size: 22pt; text-align:center; padding: 0px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; max-width:100px; height:163px"></td>
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; max-width:100px;  height:163px">I4</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; max-width:100px; height:163px">2</td>
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; max-width:100px; height:163px">I3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

se vería así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que el problema expuesto en la pregunta se refiere al alto y no al ancho

Comment: si, efectivamente como dice @Alvaro Montoro la idea es mantener el alto de las celdas fijo... intenté con **max-height** pero creo que esa propiedad no existe , porque no funcionó...

Comment: max-height si existe. En caso de mantener el alto puede usarla

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utiliziar 'min' y 'max' 'height' y 'width' para forzar las dimensiones del contenedor, en este caso tu 'td', pero además puedes darle propiedades al texto para que no se salga del mismo utilizando como en el ejemplo que aquí de dejo: 'text-overflow: ellipses' para que salgan puntos suspensivos, 'overflow-wrap:break-word' para que se rompa la palabra y salte de linea una vez ocupe todo el espacio asignado, y 'white-space:nowrap' para corregir que el contenedor se deforme si sobrepasa su espacio límite:

```css
table.tabla_televisor {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background: #82FA58;
  border: 0px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

table.tabla_televisor tr {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  /* PARA MARCAR LA SEPARACION LAS CELDAS DE LA TABLA  */
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

table.tabla_televisor td {
  border: 3px solid #000;
  /* PARA MARCAR LA SEPARACION LAS CELDAS DE LA TABLA  */
  max-height: 163px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 80px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="tabla_televisor" style="font-size: 22pt; text-align:center; padding: 0px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; width:180px; height:163px"></td>
    <td style="font-size: 50pt; color: black; width:180px; height:163px">I4</td>
  </tr>
  
   <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">2</td>
    <td style="color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">I3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">2</td>
    <td style="color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">I333333333333333333333333333333333333333</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr style="height:163px">
    <td style="font-size: 130pt; color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">2</td>
    <td style="color: red; max-width:180px; height:163px">I33</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```